# Rails production with puma and nginx puma.sock missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I'm setting up my rails production server on digital ocean with puma and nginx.

Following tutotials I have entered this in my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server unix:/home/deploy/appname/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
```

But on the server the folder home/deploy/appname/shared/sockets/ is empty.

I double checked the tutorials and none of them mentions creating such file.

If I run `ps aux | grep puma`I get

> root      2076  0.0  0.3  52992  3544 pts/0    T    05:51   0:00 sudo
>   nano require capistrano/puma root      2077  0.0  0.3  23872  3888
>   pts/0    T    05:51   0:00 nano require capistrano/puma rails     2407
>   0.0  0.0  14484  1012 pts/0    S+   06:38   0:00 grep puma

which it doesn't really makes sense to me as I'm not using capistrano.

My question is. How is puma.sock created? During puma installation? What step have I missed if that directory is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `capistrano` you need to start `puma` with `-b` option to create sock file:

```
puma -b unix:///__abs_path_to_your_app__/puma.sock
```

and in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` you need to change path to `.sock` file:

```
server unix:///__abs_path_to_your_app__/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
```